# Http load testing with bytes counting

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

I need some possibility to conduct load testing of our REST API with traffic counting.

For example to run 20 concurrent user for 1 hour. As a result I want to get information about responses (avg time, delays, etc) and overall traffic that has been produced.

I overlooked JMeter and Gatling, but found no possibilities to count bytes.

I don't really need big amount of concurrent users (100 would be enough) and high throughput (more than 10 requests per second from single user).

My goal is just to produce some load on our system and to check that it shows correct statistic data.

Comment: I need bytes received from server, e.g. downloaded bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default JMeter should be saving sent and received bytes in .jtl results file

[image: JMeter .jtl results file]

If it doesn't - add the next lines to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.sent_bytes=true
```

Also make sure you have `HttpClient4` implementation selected on the "Advanced" tab of [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults))

[image: JMeter HTTP Request]

Comment: Thanks for screenshots!

Answer (score 3):

JMeter (checked with latest 3.3) already [save sent/received bytes](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html) by default, you can see in Listener's Configure button:

```
Save sent bytes count

Save received bytes count
```

You will get in jtl file saved columns `..,bytes,sentBytes..`